# I want to insert data from a single form into multiple table both table contains relations

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php and trying to learn. I m also trying to make an web application "school management system".
I am getting problem while i am inserting records in student and parents table from the same form, the form is ok and its inserting record in student table but not in parents table.
in parents and student table student_id is common and in student table student_id contain primary key and in parents table it contain foreign key.
my code is given below:

---

```
<?php>
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $reg = $_POST['reg_no'];
 $s_name = $_POST['student_name'];
 $s_father = $_POST['student_father'];
 $p_last_name = $_POST['parent_lastname'];
 $s_birth = $_POST['student_birth'];
 $p_phone = $_POST['parent_phone'];
 $p_address = $_POST['parent_address'];
 $school_name = $_POST['school_name'];
 $batch = $_POST['session_batch'];
 //filtering variables
     $reg_no = mysql_real_escape_string($reg);
 $student_name = mysql_real_escape_string($s_name);
 $student_father = mysql_real_escape_string($s_father);
 $parent_last_name= mysql_real_escape_string($p_last_name);
 $student_birth = mysql_real_escape_string($s_birth);
 $parent_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($p_phone);
 $parent_address = mysql_real_escape_string($p_address);
 $school = mysql_real_escape_string($school_name); 
 $batch = mysql_real_escape_string($batch);
     //connecting to db by including db file
     include_once('include/dbconnect.php');

        $db_select = mysql_select_db($server_db_name,$db_connect);
        if ($db_connect)
        {
$student_query = "INSERT INTO students (school_id, session_id, student_name,
    student_father, student_birthdate, registration_no) VALUES
    ('$school','$batch','$student_name','$student_father','$student_birth','$reg_no')";
    $s_query = mysql_query($student_query) or DIE ("error. while inserting records in
    student");
    /* here im trying to select student_id which is inserted above to insert data in
      parents table*/
     $id_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = $student_name
     LIMIT 1") or DIE ("Could complete the id query");
     while ($id_result = mysql_fetch_array($id_query))
     { $s_id = $id_result['student_id'];
           $parent_query = "INSERT INTO parents (school_id, student_id, parent_name,
             parent_lastname, parent_phone, parent_address)
          VALUES('$school','$s_id','$student_father','$parent_last_name',
           '$parent_phone','$parent_address')";
        $p_query = mysql_query($parent_query);
            if (!$parent_query) { echo "error. while inserting records in student"; }
              }
            mysql_close($db_connect);
    header('location:admin.php?student');
    }
    else {
    echo "Error While Connecting to server";
    }
              }else {
            header('location:admin.php?error');
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: am i doing this in correct way?

Comment: the records are not inserting in parents table

Comment: i want the student_id also inserted into the parents table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = $student_name ...  a u sure?

Comment: hm. nice check. i should changed it to student_name, let me chk now

Comment: same error "Could complete the id query" the query is not selecting the id. i tried SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_name = $student_name

Comment: I found my mistake i forget to add apostrophe with $student_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like JOE LEE has mentioned in above snippet,

```
$generated_key=mysql_insert_id();
```

// this line of code actually returns the auto generated id, of course I am guessing you want the auto incremented value from the student table for the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

find id u Last inserted,  use mysql_insert_id()

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf ("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```